# In libseccomp, what is scmp_filter_ctx? And what is it used for?

Tags: bpf, seccomp

What actually stores `scmp_filter_ctx` since it's defined as `void`?
[See seccomp header file](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/master/include/seccomp.h.in#L54-L57).

In general what is a `context` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not defined as `void` but `void *`, so it's a generic pointer.

From a quick glance at the file you link I would say it points to some object which structure you can't access (and don't need to know about). The `context` seems to be the object storing the information seccomp needs to work, and you only need to init, update or use it through the API functions exposed in that header file.

If you really want to see what's inside, just read the source :). In [`src/api.c`](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/78497a5d1da200ab0356e1189f5efb8724ad70a1/src/api.c#L200) it's apparently casted as a [`struct db_filter_col *`](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/78497a5d1da200ab0356e1189f5efb8724ad70a1/src/db.h#L142), which of course is not exposed to users.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to open another topic , but here https://lwn.net/Articles/494252/ there is a function seccomp_gen_bpf that I can't find it in the source code. Do you know if it has been removed or renamed?

Comment: `git log -S seccomp_gen_bpf` is your friend ;). It was apparently renamed in [this commit](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/commit/340c43352dc0dc2e48acc2cb08cb4e5d4da995ea).